# Msssql assign non null value when grouped by another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following txn_table table:

```
Code      Category      Date    TicketRevenue  SnackRevenue  BeverageRevenue
A11       AA            8/14        100             80             60
AT201     BB            8/19        300             150            100
AT201     NULL          8/19        50              50             40
```

I would like to fetch the data such that it would display the sum of the Revenue columns, grouped by the column:code. If category column has NULL for one of the rows with the same `code` (for example the category differs in the 2 AT201     entries), I would like a BB (Non-null) value to be assigned in that spot. Category can have only two possible values for each code i.e. Non-NULL and Null Value.

Example layout:

```
Code      Category      Date    TicketRevenue  SnackRevenue  BeverageRevenue
AMC       AA            8/14        100             80             60
AT201     BB            8/19        350             200           140
```

I know how to add null value when it is not distinct but is it possible get non-null value there instead?

```
select Code, if(count(distinct Category)=1, Category, NULL), Date,sum(TicketRevenue),sum(SnackRevenue), sum(BeverageRevenue)
from txn_table
group by Code
```

Reference: *Values and query has been borrowed from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39882439/mysql-how-to-assign-a-null-value-to-non-matching-columns-when-using-group-by)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `max` (or `min`) which returns max non-null value from the given column or expression.

```
select Code,
    max(Category),
    date,
    sum(TicketRevenue),
    sum(SnackRevenue),
    sum(BeverageRevenue)
from txn_table
group by Code
```

Comment: cool didn't know you could use min, max on non numeric column